# Replacing QGraphicsWebView in Qt 5.7

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtwebengine, qt5.7

I'm trying to upgrade my project to Qt 5.7; Aside from the migration of QtWebkit to QtWebEngine, I have to deal with `QGraphicsWebView`, which I'm not sure with what I'm supposed to replace.

What should I use?

Comment: This stuff is unavailable for QtWebEngine, so the solution is just remove everything related to QGraphicsWebView, it will be never supported

Comment: Yes, I already got to that conclusion. My question is with *what* I can replace it. I can't just delete the code, I need to replace it with *something*

Comment: Just QWidget instead of QGraphicsWidget, anyway your code will be changed when you will use QtWebEngine

Comment: I'm not using QGraphicsWidget, I'm using QGraphicsWebView. @demonplus

Comment: OK, change QGraphicsWebView to QWebView and then port according instructions http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to show a webView inside a graphics scene you can use a `QWebEngineView` widget instead of your `QGraphicsWebView` and add it to your graphics scene with `QGraphicsscene::addWidget(view)`